# Can I Encrypt File Using PGP Desktop and decrypt it Useing OpenPG or GPG4Win & Vice Versa

Tags: pgp, pgp-desktop

I am wondering if it is possible to Encrypt using PGP Desktop and Decrypt using GPG4Win or Vice Versa
or do I have to use the same client for the two processes the encrypting and the decrypting?

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use proprietary extensions in PGP Desktop, the produced encrypted packet is compliant to OpenPGP standard and can be later processed by other OpenPGP-compatible applications and libraries including GnuPG.